# MobilePush SDK - Redirect To Web URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, redirect, mobilepush, customization, push-notification

As you all may know, there is an additional configuration in the mobile push SDK required for handling push messages redirection to a custom URL from an external source.

Following the link: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

We noticed that after implementing this, the push isn't sent at all. We removed the code, and we got the messages. meaning the issue is with the customize notifications guide.

NOTE: We haven't forgotten to enable OpenDirect.

What can be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your customization code.  The code snippets in the documentation pages are known to be working.

Comment: Already fixed it. I had a problem with customizing the channel ID. Thanks anyway!